# Serialize adding unexpected data

Tags: php

```
$post = &$_POST;
$arr = $post['articles'];
var_dump($arr);
//array (size=3)  0 => string '145' (length=3)  1 => string '123' (length=3)  2 => string '128' (length=3)

$sArr = serialize($arr);
var_dump($sArr);
//string 'a:3:{i:0;s:3:"145";i:1;s:3:"123";i:2;s:3:"128";}' (length=48)

die();
```

I have an array that I wish to serialize to store in my DB.

But the output is not as expected, I need a string like:

```
{145, 123, 128}
```

But some other data has been added - why and how can I remove it?

Comment: That is how serialization works - the output it gives is correct. You can then unserialize that data later to turn it back into an array

Comment: Um, this is how the serialize function works. I'm not sure why you expect any different behavior, specifically your required format.

Comment: PHP serialise includes all the metadata about the variable being encoded (namely its type and variable name) so it can be unserialised into the exact same state later.  The output is correct.  By the way, serialising data to put it in a relational database is a REALLY BAD IDEA!  Everybody I know who has ever done it has come to regret it.  Make use of dependant tables instead, that's what relational DBs are designed to do, after all.

Comment: Is your database in Postgresql?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for that can be found in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). it says

> useful for storing or passing PHP values around **without losing their**
>   **type and structure**

So the serialize function must encode also the value types etc. I would guess that `i` is the index, and `s` is the type "string".

To get your result, use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) instead.

Comment: Actually the `i` stands for `integer`:
    `a = array, i = integer, s = string, b = boolean, etc.` as a key in an array can be any type.
Your suggestion to use implode using the `,` delimiter may work but the example given looks more like json which can be achieved by using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

Answer (score 7):

you can use use `json_encode` for any complex data and it's standard.

```
<?php
$arr=[145, 123, 128];//considering your input is like this
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

this up will answer exactly

```
[145, 123, 128]
```

and if you need curly braces that much you can use this instead

```
echo '{'.substr(json_encode($arr),1,-1).'}';
```

Comment: For your second point, this is not how to do it. Use the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option instead. Otherwise, this is the correct answer.

Comment: to  @miken32  : but  `SON_FORCE_OBJECT` whould include indices into json too.
 like : {"0":145,"1":123,"2":128}

Comment: Good point. I just cringe whenever I see attempts to "build" JSON from strings. Though looking at the question again it's not even asking for valid JSON!

Answer (score 2):

*join* will do the magic:

```
$sArr = '{' . join(', ', $arr) . '}';
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
$sArr = implode(",", $arr);
```